# Use single variable calculus methods to find the area of the region

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Use single variable calculus methods to find the area of the region in the first quadrant bounded by the curves $y^2=3x$, $y^2=4x$, $x^2=3y$, $x^2=4y$

Could someone please show me how to go about this?

Comment: Once you've drawn the region, it's just an area bounded by a few curves. And single variable calculus does this very well

Comment: @mixedmath I'm looking for a step by step solution if possible.

Comment: Questions regarding homework assignments are more than welcome, provided that they:
Briefly explain the problem you are trying to solve—do not post your entire assignment verbatim. Explain what you tried and where you're stuck (showing your work is a good idea). Don't ask for complete solutions to the problem—we're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: @FlybyNight I was only looking for step by step so I can learn how to do it. This is one question from a whole assignment. I figured if I knew how to do this one I could accomplish the rest.

Comment: @Deekor I was only cutting-and-pasting the site guidelines.

Comment: Note the symmetry about the line $y=x$. It is nice to take advantage of that, and find the area of our region below $y=x$ and double the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, express all the functions as functions of either $x$ or of $y$. Since we are interested in the first quadrant only, we can take the positive roots where necessary. Since you're likely more comfortable using formulas expressed as functions of $x$, express each formula as $y = f(x)$.

$y^2=3x\implies y = \sqrt{3x}$,

$y^2=4x \implies y = \sqrt{4x} = 2 \sqrt x$,

$x^2=3y\implies y = \frac 13 x^2$,

$x^2=4y \implies y = \frac 14 x^2$.

Next, graph the functions, together, in one graph!

**GRAPH ADDED:** My guess is that you are being asked to find the area of the "parallelogram-like" figure in shown in the upper-left portion of the graph below, each side belonging to one and only one of the curves.

[image]

Find the exact points of intersection to help determine bounds of integration (you will likely need to sum *different* integrals to find the total area, as the upper and lower curves will change).

You'll need to find the $x$-values for each of the four points of intersection, so the area will be determined by the sum of four integrals with bounds from $x_0$ to $x_1$, $x_1$ to $x_2$, $x_2$ to $x_3$, and $x_3$ to $x_4$, respectively. You'll also need to determine which functions to use as your upper and lower curve on each interval over which you are integrating.

Comment: Deekor: Let me know how you are coming on this. I'll reply and help you along if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=\frac{x^2}{y}$ and $v=\frac{y^2}{x}$. Then your transformed region in $uv$-plane is $3\leq u\leq 4$ and $3\leq v\leq 4$ with the Jacobian $$\frac{\partial(u, v)}{\partial(x, y)}=3.$$ You can proceed from here.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you read the question, missed the 'single variable calculus' part, read the tags, saw the [tag:multivariable-calculus] there and answered. I'm not saying it doesn't belong, but I wanted to point out that this isn't what the OP asked for (though it does lead to a nice, maybe even nicer solution)

Comment: what can I say you are right? But let us leave it as an alternate solution for future readers @mixedmath.